# TabBarController and Navigation Controller - Swift - Login

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to add both a Navigation Bar Controller and a Tab Bar Controller to my application.

"First View Controller" is my first View Controller at index 0.

However, I cannot embed a Navigation Controller into First VC without incurring an error:

Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1a0a21fb8) to 'project.FirstViewController' (0x1000ae228).

Here's the code in my App Delegate:

```
 let TabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
 let controller = TabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! FirstViewController
 controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
```

I realize that there is no Navigation Controller object in my code. Should the Tab Bar Controller NOT be behind the login page?

Obviously I plan on using both a Navigation Controller and Tab Bar Controller post-login.

But how do I instantiate a Navigation Controller to have a Navigation Bar in my First VC?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your Storyboard should look like this image  [image: storyboard]

add navigation controller

this may help

Comment: Did not work. Question: is "item 2" in the diagram First VC? Also, it looks like the Navigation Controller is the root view controller in the diagram. It is competing with the Tabbar Controller. Same error.

Comment: I should also mention this is a Single View App, as I am using CoreData. Not certain if the above diagram is a Tabbar Controller by default, or not.

Comment: Both of these helped. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually almost there. From what I can read, the error states that it is unable to cast FirstViewController into `UINavigationController`. Assuming that your storyboard looks like the one in @PKT's answer, your codes should look like this.

```
let TabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let navigationController = TabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! FirstViewController
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
```

The NavigationController is important if you want to NavigationBar. though.

Comment: So, I am now getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<project.FirstViewController: 0x154539610>) has no segue with identifier 'Login''. Now I have a "logout" button in First VC with no outlet connection, just a segue identifier "Login", which worked before.

Comment: Also, I have an extra tab bar item in the Tabbar. I only need 4 tabs. But because Tabbar VC is the root view controller, and connected to the Login VC, it is passing its data to First VC with the other views. I now have 5 tabs, one clearly not in-use. I tried disabling it. Nothing.

Comment: Lastly, because I have a Navigation VC embedded in the Login VC, I can " < go back" to the Login VC from the First VC, which makes the logging in part insecure.